# PHP: Another regex I can't figure out

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble with 2 regular expressions in PHP

**1. stripping http(s):// and www.**

```
https://www.google.be/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=regex&oq=regex
http://www.google.be/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=regex&oq=regex
https://google.be/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=regex&oq=regex
http://google.be/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=regex&oq=regex

=> google.be/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=regex&oq=regex
```

**2. 3-30 characters, may contain a-zA-Z0-9.-_* but need at least one letter or number**

```
Valid: -_l*96d.*
Invalid: *-_.
```

I've searched so long without any result so please help !

Many thanks!

Comment: I need it for CakePHP validation, so i needs to be a regex

Comment: For the first problem, take the second match from:

    ^https?:\/\/(www\.)?(.*)$

The second seems trickier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    preg_replace('/^(http|https):\/\/(www\.)?/i', '', $url)
```

Comment: /^.*(?=.{3,33})(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9\-\*_\.]).*$/

Answer (score 1):

The second regex would look like this:

```
'/^(?=[0-9a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9\-\*_\.]{3,30)$/'
```

Comment: seems not to be working, it says ...-a is false

Comment: what *should* be working but isn't. Give me an example.

Comment: Is not working for ...-a either